# Putting parts of a text file into a list

Tags: python, list

I have this text file and I need certain parts of it to be inserted into a list.

The file looks like:

```
blah blah
.........

item: A,B,C.....AA,BB,CC....

Other: ....

....
```

I only need to rip out the A,B,C.....AA,BB,CC..... parts and put them into a list. That is, everything after "Item:" and before "Other:"

This can be easily done with small input, but the problem is that it may contain a large number of items and text file may be pretty huge. Would using rfind and strip be as efficient for huge input as for small input, algorithmically speaking?

What would be an efficient way to do it?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  Is the pattern you describe present only once or multiple times in the file?  What does the file look like *exactly*?

Comment: Yes the pattern appears only once in the file. The description above is pretty much how the file looks like..

Comment: My apology for not putting in details. I can easily implement code for a small file using rfind and strip, but my question is more on the algorithmic aspect, when I have to deal with huge input. So I guess the question really is, how efficient is rfind() when dealing with huge input?

Comment: Rather than reading in the entire file, from your description, it sounds like you can simply read the file in line by line (which is very easy in Python -- the "with-open-as/for line in file" idiom is described everywhere).  Wait until you find one that starts with "item:", and then start collecting everything until you see a line beginning with "Other:"

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc: Can you please explain how `rfind()` comes into play? As I demonstrate in my answer, there's really no need for it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to match a start code, collect data while splitting on commas to make a list, and continue until you match a stop code?  Or do you want to match a start code, collect entire lines, and continue until a stop code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see no need for `rfind()` nor `strip()`.

It looks like you're simply trying to do:

```
start = 'item: '
end = 'Other: '
should_append = False
the_list = []
for line in open('file').readlines():
    if line.startswith(start):
        data = line[len(start):]
        the_list.append(data)
        should_append = True
    elif line.startswith(end):
        should_append = False
        break
    elif should_append:
        the_list.append(line)

print the_list
```

This doesn't hold the whole file in memory, just the current line and the list of lines found between the start and the end patterns.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about efficiency specifically, reading in the file and comparing it line by line will net O(n) average case performance.

Example by Code:

```
pattern = "item:"
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(pattern):
            # You can do what you like with it; split it along whitespace or a character, then put it into a list.
```

You're searching the entire file sequentially, and you have to compare some number of elements in the file before you come across the element you're looking for.

You have the option of building a search tree instead.  While it costs O(n) to build, it would cost O(log<sub>k</sub>n) time to search (resulting in O(n) time overall, again), where k is the number of starting characters you'd have in your list.

Comment: I don't understand why you are even talking about building a search tree.  The problem description states that there is a start code, then some comma-separated data that must be collected, then a stop code.  Why would you build a search tree to handle a problem that is easily solved with a simple state machine?  Also, it should be much faster to use the built-in features of Python, written in C, rather than build a data structure in Python and write Python code to search through it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is simple enough that it really only has two states, so you could just use a Boolean variable to keep track of what you are doing.  But the general case for problems like this is to write a state machine that transitions from one state to the next until it has worked its way through the problem.

I like to use enums for states; unfortunately Python doesn't really have a built-in enum.  So I am using a class with some class variables to store the enums.

Using the standard Python idiom `for line in f` (where `f` is the open file object) you get one line at a time from the text file.  This is an efficient way to process files in Python; your initial lines, which you are skipping, are simply discarded.  Then when you collect items, you just keep the ones you want.

This answer is written to assume that "item:" and "Other:" never occur on the same line.  If this can ever happen, you need to write code to handle that case.

EDIT: I made the start_code and stop_code into arguments to the function, instead of hard-coding the values from the example.

```
import sys

class States:
    pass

States.looking_for_item = 1
States.collecting_input = 2

def get_list_from_file(fname, start_code, stop_code):
    lst = []
    state = States.looking_for_item
    with open(fname, "rt") as f:
        for line in f:
            l = line.lstrip()
            # Don't collect anything until after we find "item:"
            if state == States.looking_for_item:
                if not l.startswith(start_code):
                    # Discard input line; stay in same state
                    continue
                else:
                    # Found item!  Advance state and start collecting stuff.
                    state = States.collecting_input

                    # chop out start_code
                    l = l[len(start_code):]

                    # Collect everything after "item":
                    # Split on commas to get strings.  Strip white-space from
                    # ends of strings.  Append to lst.
                    lst += [s.strip() for s in l.split(",")]
            elif state == States.collecting_input:
                if not l.startswith(stop_code):
                    # Continue collecting input; stay in same state
                    # Split on commas to get strings.  Strip white-space from
                    # ends of strings.  Append to lst.
                    lst += [s.strip() for s in l.split(",")]
                else:
                    # We found our terminating condition!  Don't bother to
                    # update the state variable, just return lst and we
                    # are done.
                    return lst
            else:
                print("invalid state reached somehow!  state: " + str(state))
                sys.exit(1)

lst = get_list_from_file(sys.argv[1], "item:", "Other:")
# do something with lst; for now, just print
print(lst)
```

Comment: You're saying that this is an efficient implementation?  I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, this is an efficient way to solve the problem.  You shouldn't just use the `.read()` method to read an entire file into a single string; doing it this way, you just get a line at a time.  As long as the lines are not too long, you don't need to hold too much data in memory at one time.

Comment: This would imply that the runtime is still O(n), but the memory complexity *has a chance to* be lower.  I'm still not convinced wholly that this a more efficient solution than the "implicit" string comparison.

Comment: It depends entirely on the size of the file.  Suppose your file is ten GB of data.  The sample code I wrote will process it in time proportional to the number of lines in the file.  In 32-bit Python, an attempt to use `open("filename").read()` would simply fail because 32-bit Python cannot handle 10 GB of data.  In 64-bit Python, assuming you have less than 10 GB of RAM, your RAM would fill and then your hard disk would start swapping; and disk swapping is very slow indeed.  (And if your RAM + swapfile are smaller than the size, the `.read()` call still fails.)

Comment: Of course, if your 10 GB file is all one line, the `for line in f` idiom doesn't really help.  But many files, such as system log files, have relatively short lines while possibly growing to multiple GB in size, making this technique valuable.

Comment: I just realized that you wrote an answer using the `for line in f` idiom.  My answer is no more or less efficient than yours; presumably you thought yours was efficient when you wrote it.  So I don't understand what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Your answer adds more overhead and complexity than just searching the file line-by-line; it seems to do a bit more work than what is implied.  Both run in O(n) time, which I'm not contesting.  I'm just not sure why one would want to (or need to) use enumeration and states to find a single occurrence of a phrase.

Comment: The problem was not "to find a single occurrence of a phrase."  The problem is to scan a file, looking for a start code ("item:" in the example), then collect a bunch of comma-separated string values into a list (splitting on the commas) while looking for a stop code ("Other:" in the example).  I identified two states: looking for the start code, and collecting the data.  Instead of using a Boolean variable, I used an explicit state machine, so that the code could easily be changed to handle a more complex algorithm with more states.  This is tested, working, extendable code with comments.

Answer (score 0):

Though I usually jump at the chance to employ regular expressions, I feel like for a single occurrence in a large file, it would be much more work and too computationally expensive to use regex.  So perhaps the straightforward answer (in python) would be most appropriate:

```
s = 'item:'
yourlist = next(line[len(s)+1:].split(',') for line in open("c:\zzz.txt") if line.startswith(s))
```

This, of course, assumes that 'item:' doesn't exist on any other lines that are NOT followed by 'other:', but in the event 'item:' exists only once and at the start of the line, this simple generator should work for your purposes.

Comment: (0) My understanding of the problem description is that there is a start code, then we collect the remaining data on the line and any succeeding lines until we see a stop code.  This code does not do that.  (1) Your code does not check for the stop code ("Other:") at all.  (2) I very much dislike the way you have structured this code; it is needlessly difficult to understand what is happening and how it works.  Clarity is a virtue in code, and this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer that assumes that the start code and stop code must occur at the start of a line.  This answer also assumes that the lines in the file are reasonably short.

You could, instead, read the file in chunks, and check to see if the start code exists in the chunk.  For this simple check, you could use `if code in chunk` (in other words, use the Python `in` operator to check for a string being contained within another string).

So, read a chunk, check for start code; if not present discard the chunk.  If start code present, begin collecting chunks while searching for the stop code.  In a recent Python version you can concatenate the blocks one at a time with reasonable performance.  (In an old version of Python you should store the chunks in a list, then use the `.join()` method to join the chunks together.)

Once you have built a string that holds data from the start code to the end code, you can use `.find()` and `.rfind()` to find the start code and end code, and then cut out just the data you want.

If the start code and stop code can occur more than once in the file, wrap all of the above in a loop and loop until end of file is reached.